# Trouble Importing command from Sklearn .18 with Python 3.4 in Anaconda

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using `sklearn` and need to use a neural network. I found that the latest version of `sklearn` (`.18`) had a class for the Multilayer Perceptron, a type of neural net. I grabbed the latest version of sklearn of github and put it into my anaconda folder. However, while I could import that RBM, and the other subclass in the neural network class, I couldn't import the `MLPRegressor` or `Classifier`. Here is my code:

```
from sklearn import svm, preprocessing
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, KMeans
from sklearn.neural_network.rbm import BernoulliRBM
from sklearn.neural_network.multilayer_perceptron import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network.multilayer_perceptron import MLPRegressor
```

Here is the error message:

[image]

What's going wrong?

Comment: Please include your error message as text, rather than as an off-site image!

Comment: Do you have a properly located `exceptions` folder? That is the folder that is actually not being found.

Comment: scikit-learn needs to be compiled using cython. Just dropping the source won't work.

Comment: @NathanielFord where exactly should my exceptions folder be located?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to locate a folder that is up two levels from where the script is running. Refer to the PEP: https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - in the new version of sklearn (.18), I can't just drop the source code into the folder that normal holds all my python libraries. Had to actually download sklearn off Github (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) and run the setup.